# Scope issue between jQuery request and d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm struggling with a scope question.
Basically, I am making an API request with jQuery's `$.getJSON()`
Then I intend to use the result to draw a graph with D3.js.

```
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var startDate = '2013-09-06';
var endDate = '2014-03-06';
var req = encodeURIComponent('select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO") and startDate = "' + startDate + '" and endDate = "' + endDate + '"');

var dd = $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + req + "&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.query.results.quote[0]);
});

console.log("lol");  //works fine
console.log(data);   //doesn't work
console.log(dd);     //works
console.log(dd.data);     //doesn't work
```

I am very confused.
How can I use the results of my query in d3.js?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous. This means that when you execute the code, it sends off the request. Then the code below it is executed -- nothing has come back yet. When the request returns, the handler function is called with the data. This is where you need to do everything you want to do with the data.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    // make graph
});
```

Note that D3 provides its own function for retrieving JSON:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
    // make graph
});
```